# Nuxt installation error : Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude)

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, error-handling, nuxt.js

I successfully installed Vuejs and Nodejs but got a problem when installing Nuxtjs. This is what I get. I already asked some friends but it didn't work. Thanks for your help ! :)

**Error** : Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude)

```
Rule can only have one resource source (provided resource and test + include + exclude) in {
  "use": [
    {
      "loader": "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\JS\\my-first-project\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js",
      "options": {
        "configFile": false,
        "babelrc": false,
        "cacheDirectory": true,
        "envName": "server",
        "presets": [
          [
            "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\JS\\my-first-project\\node_modules\\@nuxt\\babel-preset-app\\src\\index.js",
            {
              "corejs": {
                "version": 3
              }
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      "ident": "clonedRuleSet-30[0].rules[0].use[0]"
    }
  ]
}

  "use": [
  {
  "loader": "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\JS\\my-first-project\\node_modules\\babel-loader\\lib\\index.js",
  "options": {
  "configFile": false,
  "babelrc": false,
  "cacheDirectory": true,
  "envName": "server",
  "presets": [
  [
  "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\JS\\my-first-project\\node_modules\\@nuxt\\babel-preset-app\\src\\index.js",
  {
  "corejs": {
  "version": 3
  }
  }
  ]
  ]
  },
  "ident": "clonedRuleSet-30[0].rules[0].use[0]"
  }
  ]
  }
  at checkResourceSource (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:167:11)
  at Function.normalizeRule (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:198:4)
  at node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:110:20
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at Function.normalizeRules (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:109:17)
  at new RuleSet (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\RuleSet.js:104:24)
  at new NormalModuleFactory (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\NormalModuleFactory.js:115:18)
  at Compiler.createNormalModuleFactory (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:636:31)
  at Compiler.newCompilationParams (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:653:30)
  at Compiler.compile (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:661:23)
  at node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:77:18
  at AsyncSeriesHook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (node_modules\tapable\lib\HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:22:1)
  at AsyncSeriesHook.lazyCompileHook (node_modules\tapable\lib\Hook.js:154:20)
  at Watching._go (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:41:32)
  at node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\Watching.js:33:9
  at Compiler.readRecords (node_modules\@nuxt\webpack\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compiler.js:529:11)
```

Answer (score 30):

`npm i -D webpack@^4.46.0`  try this, it worked for me.

Comment: If you had issues with sass and sass-loader. You can use `npm i -D sass-loader@^10.1.1`

Comment: `npm i -D webpack@^4.46.0 sass-loader@^10.1.1` fixed for me. Thanks

Comment: `npm i -D webpack@^4.46.0 sass-loader@^10.1.1` - it resolved my issue. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 8):

I've had the same issue today, it seems to be related to an npm dependencies resolution issue.

I have opened an issue in [nuxt.js repository](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/8277)

In my project, the issue was present, cause of @nuxtjs/eslint-module, you can remove it and regen dependencies :

- `npm uninstall @nuxtjs/eslint-module`
- `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json`
- `npm install`

You will not longer have eslint feedbacks in your build command, but you can still use `npm run lint`, and you will be able to use nuxt until the issue will be fixed.

Comment: Additionally, if the above instructions don't fix it for you. You can downgrade to Node 14.16.0 (LTS). The underlying issue is that Webpack 5.x is installed instead of Webpack 4.x.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same error while trying to upgrade one of my old NuxtJS  projects (using sass) built on node version 12 to version 16.

To fix this, i also installed @nuxtjs/style-resources that matches my versions of `sass-loader` and `node-sass`.
To confirm, uninstall the ones you already have, and run

`npm install --save-dev node-sass sass-loader@10 fibers @nuxtjs/style-resources`

see [this article](https://dev.to/nbhankes/using-sass-in-nuxt-js-4595) for more

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I installed the most recent version of copy-webpack-plugin in Nuxt v2 project. Apparently it doesn't use webpack5 so I had to downgrade copy-webpack-plugin to last compatible version e.g. copy-webpack-plugin@4.6.0