# Nuxt: Cannot find module '@tailwindcss/jit'

Tags: nuxt.js, tailwind-css

When I run `npm run dev`, it can't find module `@tailwindcss/jit`, how should I fix ?

```
$ npm run dev

> myproject@1.0.0 dev
> nuxt


 WARN  webpack@5.37.0 is installed but ^4.46.0 is expected                                                                                                                                                                                      11:44:40

ℹ Merging Tailwind config from ~/tailwind.config.js                                                                                                                                                                            nuxt:tailwindcss 11:44:40
ℹ Parsed 4 files in 0,6 seconds                                                                                                                                                                                                   @nuxt/content 11:44:41

   ╭───────────────────────────────────────────────────────╮
   │                                                       │
   │   Nuxt @ v2.15.5                                      │
   │                                                       │
   │   ▸ Environment: development                          │
   │   ▸ Rendering:   server-side                          │
   │   ▸ Target:      server                               │
   │                                                       │
   │   Listening: http://localhost:3003/                   │
   │                                                       │
   │   Tailwind Viewer: http://localhost:3003/_tailwind/   │
   │                                                       │
   ╰───────────────────────────────────────────────────────╯

ℹ Preparing project for development                                                                                                                                                                                                             11:44:43
ℹ Initial build may take a while                                                                                                                                                                                                                11:44:43
ℹ Tailwind JIT activated                                                                                                                                                                                                       nuxt:tailwindcss 11:44:43
ℹ Discovered Components: .nuxt/components/readme.md                                                                                                                                                                                             11:44:43
✔ Builder initialized                                                                                                                                                                                                                           11:44:43
✔ Nuxt files generated                                                                                                                                                                                                                          11:44:43

 ERROR  Cannot find module '@tailwindcss/jit'                                                                                                                                                                                                   11:44:43
Require stack:
- /Users/me/myproject/node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js

  Require stack:
  - node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js
  at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:885:15)
  at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:94:19)
  at m (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:52899)
  at Resolver.f [as _require] (node_modules/jiti/dist/jiti.js:1:53712)
  at Resolver.requireModule (node_modules/@nuxt/core/dist/core.js:381:29)
  at node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:792:58
  at Array.map (<anonymous>)
  at PostcssConfig.loadPlugins (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:791:10)
  at PostcssConfig.config (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:830:14)
  at StyleLoader.postcss (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:909:39)
  at StyleLoader.apply (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:969:12)
  at WebpackClientConfig.rules (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:1357:28)
  at WebpackClientConfig.config (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:1537:21)
  at WebpackClientConfig.config (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:1708:26)
  at WebpackBundler.getWebpackConfig (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:2016:19)
  at WebpackBundler.build (node_modules/@nuxt/webpack/dist/webpack.js:2023:12)
```

`tailwind.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  prefix: 'tw-',
  purge: [],
  darkMode: false, // or 'media' or 'class'
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  variants: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Comment: Can you share your `package.json`?

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `jit: true` from `nuxt.config.js`
- Add `mode: 'jit'` to `tailwind.config.js`:

```
module.exports = {
    mode: 'jit'
}
```

[source](https://github.com/nuxt-community/tailwindcss-module/issues/341#issuecomment-834876156)

Although it might not be linked to TailwindCSS, I also had to clean a node module after the fix:

```
npm uninstall @nuxtjs/eslint-module
rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json
npm install
```

[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64620120/nuxt-installation-error-rule-can-only-have-one-resource-source-provided-resou)

Comment: How is `@nuxtjs/eslint-module` anyhow related to TailwindCSS?

Comment: @kissu I didn't say it's linked, just that I had to fix it as well, in case someone would go through the same issue. I'll edit my answer about it.